# Looping with JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently got a loop which looks like this:

```
$("#formen").on("submit", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#result").html('');
  var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
    order: "viewCount",
    part: "snippet",
    type: "video",
    q: encodeURIComponent($("#search").val()).replace(/%20/g, "+"), //encode ändrar mellanslag(%20) till  + istället..
    maxResults: 15
  });

  request.execute(function(response) {
    var results = response.result;
    console.log(results);

    $.each(results.items, function(index, item) {

      var tidId = item.id.videoId;
      var tid = gapi.client.youtube.videos.list({
        part: "contentDetails",
        id: tidId
      });

      tid.execute(function(response) {
        var svaret = response.result;
        console.log(svaret);

        $.each(svaret.items, function(index, item) {
          var dur = moment.duration(item.contentDetails.duration);
          var timeHTML = '<p class="tid">' + dur.format('HH:mm:ss', {
            trim: false
          }) + "</div>";
          $("#result > div").eq(index).append(timeHTML);
        });
      });
      $.get("item.php", function(data) {
        $("#result").append(tplawesome(data, [{
          "title": item.snippet.title,
          "yturl": item.snippet.thumbnails.high.url,
          "videoid": item.id.videoId,
          "channelTitle": item.snippet.channelTitle
        }]));
      });
    });
  });
});
```

From this i get 8 different types of numbers. They get appended inside my result div, however inside my result div i got 8 children that I would want the data inside instead. But if I append it directly into the children I get 8 data in each children which I dont want.

```
<div id = "result">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

I've tried multiple things but none of them have seem to work since if I remove `JSON.data` to .children the data gets undefined. Has anyone solved something simular?

Comment: you're appending the same thing each time through the loop. You need to refer to something in `item`.

Comment: What is `JSON.data`? `JSON` is a built-in object in the browser, you shouldn't be changing it.

Comment: Thought it was called Json data, its the data I get from Json

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should index the child divs in `result`.

```js
const jsonData = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

$.each(jsonData, function(index, item) {
    $("#result > div").eq(index).append(item);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "result">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work for me,  now all disapers instead

Comment: It would help if you showed what's in `JSON.data` and what you want the final result to be.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how it works.

Comment: It works as intended for you then

Comment: Guess my code is wrong somehow, sorry for wasting your time